# Why are code actions displayed in the problems view limited to quick fixes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54803#issuecomment-407507429) it is said:

> For quick fixes in the problems view however, we do request that
>   extensions only provide quick fixes and will filter out anything that
>   isn't marked as such

Our extension (SonarLint) provide code actions like "Show rule description" or "Disable rule". Those code actions are triggering commands. They are not strictly speaking quick fixes (arguably, disabling the rule is a quick fix, but showing the rule description is definitely not). Still I think it would be very convenient to have those commands displayed in the content menu in the problems view. Is there a reason for this choice?

Comment: Well, I imagine it's just so that refactorings and such don't show up there. Why not just use QuickFix for "Show rule description" to, or would that have some negative effects?

Comment: The effect (not sure it is negative) is that those commands will also appear in the quick fix menu you can trigger in the code editor from the diagnostic hover. Previously they were only accessible from the light bulb.